# Генерация всех символов в php

Tags: циклы, символы, php

Привет всем!

Я хочу сделать генерацию всех символов но не как не могу додуматься как сделать.

Так вот нужен такой скрипт на php который будет генерировать слова с букв пример:

```
$string = 'abc';
```

Ответ должен быть таким:

> a, b, c, aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc, aaa, aab, aac, и т.д

то есть чтобы все символы так прошли.

Да и еще есть макс и мин то есть:

```
$min = 2; // минимальное количество символов

$max = 4; // максимальное количество символов
```

Тогда будет так:

> aa, ab, ac, bb, ba, bc ... aaaa ... cccc то есть до 4 так как это макс

Comment: aaaa, abab тоже подходят? или по какому принципу формируется слово?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае слова представляют собой p-ричную систему счисления. Количество комбинаций будет p^n штук. где p - длина алфавита (в вашем примере $string = 'abc' - длина алфавита 3), n - длина слова (от 2х до 4х).

Чтоб было очевиднее, представьте себе словарь '0123456789' и длину слов от 2 до 4. соответственно вам надо получить все слова от '00' до '99' (10^2 штук), от '000' до '999'(10^3 штук) и от '0000' до '9999' (10^4 штук).

Циклом для каждой длины слова (от 2х до 4х в вашем случае) бегите от 0 до p^n, проверяйте остаток для каждого разряда, получайте номер буквы в алфавите.

Подробнее про системы счисления читайте, например, в википедии [rus](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Системы_счисления) или [eng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system).